# Trying to create a list that I can loop through selecting specifc data

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I'm not sure why when I attempt to call forth data from the following code I get NULL values. I'm also not getting an error message, so I'm not too sure where to start in addressing the issue.

I'd like to be able to possibly put this into a data frame/ table, but at this point I'd like to be able to get the total deaths for 2019 and/or get the total amount of deaths for each state in a particular year.

Attempted:

```
years <- c(2018, 2019, 2020, 2021)

yearly_totals <- list()
state_totals <- list()
mcod_totals <- list()
age_range_totals <- list()


for (year in years) {
    
    yr_data <- mcod_df[mcod_df$year == year, ]
    
    # lists for storage
      yearly_totals[[as.character(year)]] <- sum(yr_data$deaths)

  state_totals[[as.character(year)]] <- yr_data %>%
        group_by(state = state) %>%
        summarise(total_deaths = sum(deaths))
  mcod_totals[[as.character(year)]] <- yr_data %>%
        group_by(mcod = multiple_cause_of_death) %>%
        summarise(tot_mcod = sum(deaths))
    
  age_range_totals[[as.character(year)]] <- yr_data %>%
        group_by(state, age_range = five_year_age_groups) %>%
        summarise(age_range_tot = sum(deaths))
    
  }
```

To Call:

```
yearly_totals[["2020"]]
state_totals[["2020"]]
cat("State Totals for 2020:\n")
print(state_totals[["2020"]], row.names = FALSE)
```

Result:

```
> yearly_totals[["2020"]]
NULL
> state_totals[["2020"]]
NULL
> print(state_totals[["2020"]], row.names = FALSE)
NULL
```

Comment: I think you need to look a little closer at your use of `yr_data`, as against say, `yr_data[year]`, just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't considering the NULL/NA values in my data. Updated/corrected code below:

```
 years <- c(2018, 2019, 2020, 2021)
    
    yearly_totals <- list()
    state_totals <- list()
    mcod_totals <- list()
    age_range_totals <- list()
    
    for (year in years) {
        yr_data <- mcod_df[mcod_df$year == year, ]


##### skip year if no data
    if (nrow(yr_data) == 0) {
      cat("No data for year", year, "\n")
      next 
    }
##### Lists to store results w/ consideration for NA/NULL values
      yearly_totals[[as.character(year)]] <- sum(yr_data$deaths)

      state_totals[[as.character(year)]] <- yr_data %>%
        filter(!is.na(state)) %>%
        group_by(state = state) %>%
        summarise(total_deaths = sum(deaths, na.rm = TRUE))

      mcod_totals[[as.character(year)]] <- yr_data %>%
      filter(!is.na(multiple_cause_of_death)) %>%
      group_by(mcod = multiple_cause_of_death) %>%
      summarise(tot_mcod = sum(deaths, na.rm = TRUE))


      age_range_totals[[as.character(year)]] <- yr_data %>%
      filter(!is.na(state) & !is.na(five_year_age_groups)) %>%
      group_by(state, age_range = five_year_age_groups) %>%
      summarise(age_range_tot = sum(deaths, na.rm = TRUE))
    }
```